# Shared Libraries in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

Is there any provision to add all the jars under `Websphere` `lib` folder to shared libraries one which I had created? Do I need to specify each and every jar in the shared library text area or is it enough to provide it as below?

```
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\Websphere\Appserver\lib
```

Will this statement keep all jars available in the `lib` folder in the classpath?

Answer (score 5):

Adding jars to the WebSphere Application Server lib directory is not a good idea, see [Best Practice for using common application files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006159#wherenot).  You would typically create shared libraries for these jars and associate them with your applications as described at the IBM Knowledge Center topic [Creating shared libraries](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_create.html).